How to prevent GitLab Runner from automatically masking variables on protected branch?
Gitlab runner automatically masks certain CI/CD variables (on protected branch pipelines), that looks like UUIDs  (like "79c14111-6272-4222-ba15-0abbb96efbc2") to prevent accidental exposure of sensitive data.
I have a problem that I can't use a variable, because it's being tuned into string [MASKED]
The "masked" checkbox in GitLab's settings for this variable is not checked.
Example:
job in .gitlab-ci.yml:
Build an App:
  stage: build
  script: 
     - build_app

In the build_app script:
app_store_connect_api_key(
   app_id: ENV['APP_ID'],
)

The app_store_connect_api_key function fails because ENV['APP_ID'] returns [MASKED] instead of the actual value.

And for pipelines which are not executed on a protected branch the variable is visible?

Yes. I also use 2 more CICD variables in this job, that are short, simple strings, they are both usable in protected/unprotected branches without an issue.


I would suggest trying to do a prefix infront of your UUID

APP_ID: "prefix-79c14111-6272-4222-ba15-0abbb96efbc2"

In your script remove the prefix, perhaps gitlab has so restrictions on it, add this to your script.
app_store_connect_api_key(
app_id: ENV['APP_ID'].sub(/^prefix-/, '')
)


Another solution might be to modify your .gitlab.ci.yaml using this.
variables:
  APP_ID: "prefix-79c14111-6272-4222-ba15-0abbb96efbc2"

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - app_id=$(echo $APP_ID | sed 's/^prefix-//')
    - app_store_connect_api_key(app_id: $app_id)

Finally, in most cases, even though the "masked" checkbox is not checked, double-check if there are other settings or group-level settings that might enforce this behavior. make sure no conflicting rules, I am guessing you are using gitlab ultimate.
